# support Toolbar Versus support search View

Tags: android, android-support-library, material-design

i have a problem with support Toolbar. when i collapse search View. All Toolbar items (ProgressBar in my case) is set To View.VISIBLE , And nor in SearchView nor in SupportMenuItem is no listener when search View finishes collapsing, to manualy return my items Visibility.

my Toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:maxHeight="30dip"
        android:minHeight="30dip"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And on create menu options

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    final SupportMenuItem searchItem = (SupportMenuItem) menu
            .findItem(R.id.search);

    searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);


    searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View view,boolean queryTextFocused) {
                    if (!queryTextFocused) {
                        searchItem.collapseActionView();
                        searchView.setQuery("", false);

                    }

                }
            });


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

And actual question how to restore needed Toolbar items visibility?

reference to "All items in custom Toolbar are set to View.VISIBLE after closing SearchView"
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78160

**UPDATE found solution**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/holder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:maxHeight="30dip"
            android:minHeight="30dip"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Seems like search View collapse only affects direct children of Toolbar. :)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Feel free to post your own solution as an answer and mark it accepted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/holder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:maxHeight="30dip"
        android:minHeight="30dip"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Seems like search View collapse only affects direct children of Toolbar. Hope some of you this post will be useful.